# Hooking up Express.js with Angular 2

Tags: angular, express

I'm trying to get Express to reroute all requests to my Angular 2 app.
Further I want Express to point to a development version of my Angular 2 app (NOT some dist folder which will only be built occasionally).

There is an OUTDATED video that shows how to do this (but it is outdated):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFP0oXNNveg

[image]

Does anyone know how I would do this with most recent version of Angular 2 ?

Comment: What do you mean by _I want Express to point to a development version of my Angular 2 app (NOT some dist folder which will only be built occasionally)._?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation on express+angular? http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/789/getting-started-with-angular-2/26878/getting-started-with-angular-2-with-node-js-expressjs-backend-http-example-incl#t=201703191911584739807